# Serialize javascript object to json and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http-post

I am using to a jQuery post method to send some data to a server. Rather than constructing the JSON string myself, I would like to simply use a JavaScript object. When I get the return string (in JSON) I would like to automatically construct a corresponding JavaScript object.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Checkout `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` in [JSON2 documentation](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Example:

```
myData = JSON.parse(text); // from json string to js object

var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer); // js object to json string
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

If the JSON object is available, you can use :

```
var aString = JSON.stringify(anObject);
```

to transform an object into JSON string.

You can also convert a string into an object with

```
var obj = JSON.parse(aString)
```

To be sure that JSON is available, you can include this file https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 3):

you should use Douglas Crockford's [JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

That way, you could:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

or

```
var Obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: You can do that anyway in modern browsers. JSON2 is a polyfill (worth using though)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) you don't have to care about stringifying and parsing json, jquery does it for you.

Comment: Good thing to know, indeed. Same if you use $.ajax with "json" as dataType.

Comment: @CronosS, yep. `getJSON` is just a shorthand for $.ajax with "json" as dataType.