# How to serialize Json javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, serialization

I need to serialize an object to JSON, in javascript.
How I can do it? I google it, but im not found the solution.

All the response are "You mustn't serialize Json in javascript, you must serialize in other language as Java, C#, so on"

Without use JQuery.

Comment: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Also see [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: exist other solution without use JQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` in JSON2 documentation

Example:

```
myData = JSON.parse(text); // from json string to js object

var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer); // js object to json string
```

if you want to know about more checkout this link
[Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: it works well, thanks

Comment: Please don't [copy other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292823/serialize-javascript-object-to-json-and-back). If the question is a duplicate, vote to close it as such.